# Loading image asynchronously in WPF using binding converter

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, binding, converters

I have a Image control with binding settings like this:

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentItem, Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

And the `ImgConverter` is:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string uri = null;

            Compressor.Unzip((value as Zipfile));

            uri = string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", Compressor.TempPath, value.ToString());

            return uri;

        }
```

The `Compressor.Unzip(...)` method does take some time. I set the binding `IsAsync=True` but it doesn't work(NOT on converter but only on path?). How can I handle this asynchronously?

Comment: freeze for a moment till the is loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Binding.IsAsync` property only affects the property getter, but not the binding converter. So you may consider to replace the converter by an additional view model property like `CurrentImage` which you can bind to asynchronously without converter.

Comment: @Clemens Any samples? I'm not familiar with MVVM. Thanks

Comment: Just add another property to the class where `CurrentItem` is defined.

Comment: @Clemens I used `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` so the `CurrentItem` is not defined by myself.

Comment: Ok, then you seem to be binding to the CurrentItem of a CollectionView. Is the source collection just a collection of strings (e.g. zip file names)?

Comment: @Clemens Not string but custom class type.

Comment: Which is Zipfile, right? I'll prepare an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a readonly `Image` property to your Zipfile class, and move the converter code to the property getter:

```
public class Zipfile
{
    ...

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            Compressor.Unzip(this);
            var uri = string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", Compressor.TempPath, this.ToString());
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
        }
    }
}
```

Then write your binding like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.Image, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I met some thread problems, it is the best solution anyway.

Comment: @SeanC. how did you fix your thread problems? my images never show up

Comment: @Julien Like he said, do the trick in the getter. The converter will not work asynchronously. If that does not work for you, check if your image source has been triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Multibinding** with two binding, First is self image control and second is your current binding, in converter you can call async your method to unzip the file and in callback you can set image path(refer to first binding);
Also you can see this sample:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fc238ea-194e-4f29-bcbd-9a3d4bdb2180/async-loading-of-bitmapsource-in-value-converter?forum=wpf

Comment: It seems like this solution is to change the source property in converter. The source property is already bound. Will this twist the binding setting?